# What is the functional shape assumed by a flexible rod?

Tags: potential, continuum-mechanics, variational-calculus

Be L a flexible rod. Say that it is very difficult to significantly stretch it, so that we can uniquely identify a point on it by a parameter $l \in [0, L]$ where $L$ is its length.

Be $C$ a set of constraints in the form $(l, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dl}})$ so that each of those constraints forces the point in $l$ to stay in position $\mathbf{x}$, with its derivative against $l$ also fixed. This is a constraint that fixes some points in some positions, and also their orientation.

(Obviously, say that for each $c, c'$ constraints, $|l_{c} - l_{c'}| \geq |\mathbf{x}_c-\mathbf{x}_{c'}|$, so that the constraint doesn't force points to stay more far apart from each other than the distance on the rod allows).

Now, my intuition says that the shape assumed by the rod will minimize some bending potential. I tried to make some variational calculations and I think I came out with the only constraint that the fourth derivative of $\mathbf{x}(l)$ must be null everywhere, but I don't think this completely defines its functional form.

So, what is the functional form of $\mathbf{x}(l)$? Are there multiple solutions? Which are them?

Comment: In the absence of any other external interactions, what you have derived as to the vanishing of the fourth derivative, is absolutely right. Now, in order to fix the shape of the rod, you will need to fix the constraints and the boundary conditions (clamped, anchored or free).

Comment: This is part of [Euler-Bernoulli beam theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory).